Unit tests failing after Angular 17 upgrade
we recently upgrade from angular 15 to 17. since then we have been facing JEST related errors.
I have tried to investigate a bit on other stackoverflow forums but did not find a relevant one.

The jest tests should pass in spite of the upgrade

Please add code and data as text (using code formatting), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and many more reasons. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.
